# React JS add 'disabled' class to multiple indexes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wanting to add a disabled class should the user click an element from a list.

Currently this is working for each item the user clicks on however, the class needs to stay if clicked on other indexes for example:

If the user clicks on any element within the list add "disabled", if the user clicks on any OTHER element add the class "disabled" and keep all other disabled classes unless user selects remove from the item.

Here is my state object containing data:

```
insightData: [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Bill shock',
        isSelected: false,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Bill shock',
        isSelected: false,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bill shock',
        isSelected: false,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Bill shock',
        isSelected: false,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Bill shock',
        isSelected: false,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Bill shock',
        isSelected: false,
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Bill shock',
        isSelected: false,
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Bill shock',
        isSelected: false,
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Bill shock',
        isSelected: false,
    },
]
```

Update function:

```
updateInsights(index) {
        const { selectedInsights, insightData } = this.state;

        this.setState({
            selectedInsights: true,
            insightData: insightData.map(item => ({
            ...item,
            isSelected: item.id === index

            }))
        })

    }
```

Usage:

```
<ul>
    {this.state.insightData.map((item, z) => {
        const disabled = this.state.insightData[z].isSelected;

        return (
            <li key={z}>
                <span className="insight-title">{item.title}</span>
                <span className={classNames("add", {disabled})} onClick={() => this.updateInsights(item.id)}>Add to project</span>
            </li>
        )
    })}

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the condition like this.

```
isSelected: item.id === index ? true : item.isSelected
```

Your updated function `updateInsights` should be look like below.

```
updateInsights(index) {
        const { selectedInsights, insightData } = this.state;

        this.setState({
            selectedInsights: true,
            insightData: insightData.map(item => ({
            ...item,
            isSelected: item.id === index ? true : item.isSelected
            }))
        })

    }
```

Hope this will work for you!